# Listado en una tabla desde un json

Tags: javascript, jquery

La idea es al presionar el botón me muestre el listado de países dentro de una tabla como esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal y como esta el código al presionar el botón me muestra todo en una sola fila pero no he podido hacer que el resultado me lo muestre en 5 filas.

```js
var countries = '[{ "code": "CO", "name": "Colombia", "flag_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/co.gif" },' +
  '{ "code": "PE", "name": "Perú", "flag_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/pe.gif" },' +
  '{ "code": "EC", "name": "Ecuador", "flag_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/ec.gif" },' +
  '{ "code": "BO", "name": "Bolivia", "flag_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/bo.gif" }]';

$(".wrapper").on("click", function(){
 var response = $.parseJSON(countries);
 $(".wrapper").append("<table><tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>Flag</th></tr></table>")
    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
        var tr = $('<tr>').append(
         $('<td>').text(item.code),
            $('<td>').text(item.name),
            $('<td><img src="'+ item.flag_url +'">')
        ); 
        $(".wrapper").append(tr)
        $(".wrapper button").hide()
    });
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
}
table { width: 100%; }
table th, table td { padding: 7px 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Show Countries</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button>Mostrar paises</button>
  </div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="app.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el encabezado de la tabla (los elementos `th`) sí los estás incluyendo en el elemento `table` pero el resto de las filas no.

Deberías añadir todas las filas a la misma tabla:

```js
var countries = '[{ "code": "CO", "name": "Colombia", "flag_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/co.gif" },' +
  '{ "code": "PE", "name": "Perú", "flag_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/pe.gif" },' +
  '{ "code": "EC", "name": "Ecuador", "flag_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/ec.gif" },' +
  '{ "code": "BO", "name": "Bolivia", "flag_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/bo.gif" }]';

$(".wrapper").on("click", function(){
 var response = $.parseJSON(countries);
  var $table = $('<table></table>');
 $table.append("<tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>Flag</th></tr>")
  $.each(response, function(i, item) {
      var tr = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.code),
          $('<td>').text(item.name),
          $('<td><img src="'+ item.flag_url +'">')
      ); 
      $table.append(tr);
    });
    $(".wrapper").append($table)
    $(".wrapper button").hide()
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
}
table { width: 100%; }
table th, table td { padding: 7px 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Show Countries</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button>Mostrar paises</button>
  </div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="app.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda me funciono